# Eigenvalues to a product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let A and B be Hermitian matrices. I want to determine if the sum of the diagonal elements of AB is real. In other words, I want to determine the eigenvalues of AB and investigate if the sum of them will be real.

I have proven that the eigenvalues of A and B respectively will be real and now I am interested in showing what the eigenvalues for AB will be.

I know that the eigenvalues to AB can be complex since I have found an example for it, but it seems like the complex eigenvalues always appear as conjugates. This would lead to trace (AB) being real. Is this a correct assumption? If yes, then I would appreciate if someone could give me a hint on how to prove this.

So far I have mostly tried to prove it using the scalar product but have been unsuccessful and it feels like I will not be able to solve this problem using that method (only at least...).

Another idea I have is to use the fact that both A and B can be diagonalized with a basis of orthogonal eigenvectors per the spectral theorem, but I have not been able to show anything with this either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are real. Therefore is $A$ and $B$ are diagonal hermitian matrix then: $$AB=^*A^*B=(BA)^*=(diagonal matrix commute)(AB)^*$$

Comment: When you say that "A and B are Diagonal hermitian matrices", do you mean that they are diagonal after the original hermitian matrices have been diagonalized?

Comment: I understand that if A and B commute then AB will be hermitian, and therefore the eigenvalues will be real. But if A and B does not commute, you suggest that I try to write AB as a (diagonal matrix)(AB)*. have I understood you correctly?